# All my view models have become dynamic on upgrading to MVC 4 (razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel, razor-2

Can anyone help me rectify an issue. I've upgraded from MVC3 to MVC4 using NuGet method in Visual Studio 2012. Now all my views' View Models have become Dynamic even though I declare their type, none of the properties can be accessed through intellisense on the view...

So for example:

```
public class MyPageModel{
 public string Test {get;set;}
}
```

My view:

```
@model MyPageViewModel
 <div>
  @Model.Test
 </div>
```

Hovering over "Model" brings up "dynamic WebPage.Model".
Hovering over "Model.Test" brings up "dynamic expression. This operation will be resolved at runtime"

Among the other usual libraries, my project references version 2 of these:
 System.Web.Razor , System.Web.WebPages, System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Am I missing a reference perhaps?

Also to add, if my Viewmodel is an IEnumerable
e.g.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyPageViewModel>
```

Hovering over the "MyPageViewModel" brings up "Validation (HTML5). Element 'MyPageViewModel' is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

I first followed the advice on this page:

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes

that didn't solve it for me, so I followed another piece of advice and completely overwrote my web.config in my Views folder with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <system.web>
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Which solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `~/Views/Web.config` contains the below sections:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your web.config against what LovelyBananas posted. For me, it was also the web.config in the /Views folder. Same thing. It still had references to MVC 3.0.0.0 after i did a nuget install MVC4 install...